# Missing some rows for a ga:source when requesting custom dimension "userType" on Reporting API v4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using the Analytics Reporting API v4 to get a report with this body:

```
{
            'viewId': XXX,
            'dateRanges': {
                'startDate': "2021-03-16",
                'endDate': "2021-04-14"
            },
            'metrics': [
                "ga:itemQuantity", "ga:itemRevenue"
            ],
            'samplingLevel': 'LARGE',
            'pageSize': 100000,
            'hideTotals': False,
            'dimensions': ["ga:source", "ga:date", "ga:dimension4"]
}
```

If I compare the total itemRevenue with what I have on Analytics interface in the "Product performance" report, I have the same results for the whole period but if I check on a subperiod I have some different numbers.

I did the same test with a `start_date="2021-04-09"` and `end_date="2021-04-15"` and this time I always have different results. The missing rows always match `ga:source=affiliation`.

If I remove the `ga:dimension4` (corresponding to userType in the interface), my results are always the same.

Could someone explain why my results are not consistent between the API and the interface?

Comment: Can we see what report it is exactly you are comparing?  Remember you need to include all of the dimension and metrics from the first report in your code.

Comment: I am not sure what do you want to see. Do you want the reports data?
On the interface I am checking the "Product performance" report, with the same columns as those requested with the API.